# MySQL left join and union

Tags: mysql, join, union

Having a database structure like this:

car

```
id, name, color
1, mercedes, red
2, volvo, blue
3, bmw, green
```

car_alt

```
id, car_id, color
1, 1, green
2, 1, blue
3, 2, red
4, 2, blue
```

I want to get such result:

```
id, name, color
1, mercedes, red
1, mercedes, green
1, mercedes, blue
2, volvo, blue
2, volvo, red
2, volvo, blue
3, bmw, green
```

Currently i use this query:

```
SELECT id, name, color
FROM car
UNION
SELECT car.id, car.name, car_alt.color
FROM car
INNER JOIN car_alt ON car.id = car_alt.id_car
```

Is there any way to do it without using `UNION`? I wonder if it's possible to just use `LEFT JOIN` adding some empty row like:

```
SELECT car.id, car.name, COALESCE(car_alt.color, car.color)
FROM car
LEFT JOIN car_alt ON car.id = car_alt.id_car OR 'GET EMPTY ROW'
```

To explain why I even ask this, when I have to join more tables to table `car`, my query looks like:

```
SELECT id, name, color,
t1.col, t2.col, t3.col, ...
FROM car
JOIN t1
JOIN t2
JOIN t3
...
UNION
SELECT car.id, car.name, car_alt.color,
t1.col, t2.col, t3.col, ...
FROM car
JOIN t1
JOIN t2
JOIN t3
...
INNER JOIN car_alt ON car.id = car_alt.id_car
```

So there's a lot of repetition in this. The only other approach that came to my mind is to move `UNION` to subquery, like

```
SELECT car.id, car.name, union.color,
t1.col, t2.col, t3.col, ...
FROM car
JOIN t1
JOIN t2
JOIN t3
...
INNER JOIN (
SELECT car.id, car.color
FROM car
UNION
SELECT car_alt.car_id, car_alt.color
FROM car_alt) union ON car.id = union.id
```

Comment: no if you want both value for first and second tables  you should use union .. the left join return  value on the same row  ..not append  rows  to others result

Comment: The clarification/specialization helps. Notify the answerers. Please read & act on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Eg contraints matter. You may be limiting your idea of what you are doing ie what result you want hence what query can express your desired result by thinking in terms of "joining to car". Eg in your example you don't need the first/outer "car join" because the necessary data is in the subquery, you could just use subquery join t1 .... But yes maybe car's indexes mean what you wrote is "better". *Details matter in optimization.* PS Did you google 'sql avoid union' etc?

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best".

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a reasonable way of doing this without `union`/`union all`.

Here is an *unreasonable* approach, using `cross join` and filtering:

```
select c.id, c.name, co.color
from (select distinct id, name from car) c cross join
     (select distinct color from car) co 
where exists (select 1 from car c2 where c2.id = c.id and c2.color = co.color) or
      exists (select 1 from car_alt ca where ca.id = c.id and ca.color = co.color);
```

This has basically restructured the logic so the `or` functionally does what the `union all` does in your version.

Comment: Thank you. It's way too complicated approach. I want to simplify my query, not the opposite.

Comment: @dompil . . . You need to fix `car_alt` so it has the information in `car`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use UNION, how about a temporary table?

```
    SELECT *
    into #Temp
    FROM car

    INSERT #Temp
    SELECT a.car_id, c.name, a.color
    FROM car_alt a INNER JOIN
         car c ON c.id = a.car_id

    SELECT *
    FROM #Temp
    ORDER BY id, name
```

Please, don't forget to DROP TABLE #Temp when done - it's good to clean up.